# JSON in Java the way it works in Javascript

Tags: java, json

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any popular Java libraries for creating and parsing JSON strings the way it's done in Javascript. I'm not looking for a mapping library or anything of that sort. I'm starting to think that working with JSON the way Javascript works might be a better alternative.

I'm looking for something that has a builder pattern for creating JSON (since we don't have multiline strings), and a way to extract elements using simple strings for the keys and also supports easily deep "linking" into the JSON string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bjson%5D+library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good JSON Java Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668862/good-json-java-library)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas similar, but those are mainly around mapping libraries. I'm looking for something slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jackson's](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) [tree model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Tree_Model_Example) may be similar to what you are asking for. Tatu has plans for adding JSONPath in the future as well. I use Jackson for several projects and can vouch for its speed and stability.

Of course, any JSON parser that creates simple hashmaps and lists can be accessed quite easily:

```
{"topkey":{"leafkey":["a", "b", "c"],"leafkey2":"blancmange"},"topkey2":42}
```

Java:

```
data.get("topkey").get("leafkey").get(1);
```

vs. JavaScript:

```
data["topkey"]["leafkey"][1]
```

Comment: That does look similar to what I was looking for, thanks. Jackson does have a lot of boilerplate, but I guess that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JSONPath. It makes it simple to query JSON structures

```
List<String> authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
```

There is a Java implementation available here http://code.google.com/p/json-path/